# Broken promise cloud firestore function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to retrieve the document for specific ids in the following cloud function. The loop (see "Block Get Major") for retrieving that information is running, but the logs show that it is executing AFTER the function returns data.
I am certain this is because this creates a new promise, and that I need to tie them together.

I've looked through a lot of the posts on here and elsewhere and am just not getting it.

It looks like I am creating a broken/dropped promise. I get the necessary data, with the exception of menteeMajor, which is undefined until later in the log files).

```js
exports.getAllMatchesMCR = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  var dbRef = db.collection("matches");
  var dbPromise = dbRef.get();
  // return the main promise
  return dbPromise.then(function(querySnapshot) {
      var results = [];
      var idx = 0;
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

        // push promise from get into results
        var matchObj = {
          mentorName: "",
          mentorEmployer: "",
          mentees: []
        }

        var mentor = doc.data();
        mentor.mentorID = doc.id;
        matchObj.mentorName = mentor.mentorID;
        matchObj.mentees = mentor.mentees;

        for (var curIDX in matchObj.mentees) {
          matchInfoObj = {};
          matchInfoObj.mentorID = matchObj.mentorID;
          matchInfoObj.mentorName = matchObj.mentorName;
          matchInfoObj.menteeName = matchObj.mentees[curIDX];

          // Block Get Major --->
          var menteeRef = db.collection('users').doc(matchObj.mentees[curIDX]);
        var getDoc = menteeRef.get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
              console.log('No such document!');
            } else {
              var userInfo = {};
              userInfo = doc.data();

              matchInfoObj.menteeMajor = userInfo.major;

              // console.log('user Major:', matchInfoObj.menteeMajor);
              return userInfo.major;
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // console.log('Error getting document', err);
            return ("No Mentee Doc")
          });
          
          console.log("in menteeInfo: ", getDoc.data());
          matchInfoObj.menteeMajor = getDoc.data();              // Block Get Major <---
          if (typeof something === "undefined") {
            console.log('After BLOCK Major is UNDEFINED:', matchInfoObj.menteeName);
          } else {
            console.log('After BLOCK :', matchInfoObj.menteeMajor);
          }

          results.push(matchInfoObj)
        }
      });
      // dbPromise.then() resolves to  a single promise that resolves 
      // once all results have resolved
      return Promise.all(results)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
});
```

Here are two screen shots for the logs that show the order based on console.log output. Keep in mind that the sort of these log records is NEWEST at the top. [Result 1 shows the start, from deployment of function and it's start, Result 2 shows the messages from the broken promise almost two minutes later.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYorz.png)

The plain text version of what I'm trying to do is:
1. collection "Users" contains information on Mentees and Mentors
2. collection "Matches" is a doc of Mentees (array) for each Mentor, or One to Many).
3. Display one row for EACH mentor/mentee connection. I have the ids, but I need to get the names and other information for both mentees and mentors.

[Plain old Result file shows that I am getting the rows I need with the Mentor ID, and the Mentee ID (labeled Mentees, that will change)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3zgp.png)
Can someone please show me the way to chain this promise?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the promise contained in getDoc.  It's not enough just to call then/catch on a promise, because catch itself return yet another promise to manage.  You have to make sure every promise is fully complete before returning the final result.

Comment: I thought that the '.then' runs when it is complete, and the '.catch' runs when it is not resolved.  I have change that part of the code to something I hoped would work based on your feedback, and now I get an error "Error getting documents: TypeError: getDoc.data is not a function at /user_code/index.js:420:58 at QuerySnapshot.forEach (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:731:22) at /user_code/index.js:378:21 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)"

Comment: In your code, getDoc is a promise, not a snapshot, so you can't just call data() on it.  The snapshot is only delivered to the then() callback.  You may need to collect all those promises and use Promise.all again to make sure that the function terminates only after all those promises are complete as well.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I'm going through some of your videos now, and I'm hopeful that this will help me understand this better.

Comment: Yeah, it can be tricky to get everything worked out, and difficult to test.

Comment: Doug, I'm still not getting this. I have watched your video "Learn JavaScript Promises (Pt.1) with HTTP Triggers in Cloud Functions - Firecasts" and duplicated (almost exactly) your example, and I do not get the data. The log shows the function running. However, I have explicit console.log messages that seems to prove that the function is not running. I'm going to create another post as the error message I get seems indicative of an environment issue.