# Cloud firebase function error promise is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I have two previous posts trying to resolve my issues, and decided I would take all of the existing code out of the equation.

I have not been able to get any promises to work. So, I am trying to duplicate the samples in Doug Stevenson's YouTube video "Learn JavaScript Promises (Pt.1) with HTTP Triggers in Cloud Functions - Firecasts". Based on the error below, I question if my environment is the reason I have been unable to get promises to work properly.

Neither of these messages appear in the console logs (not surprising to me based on the message returned.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const sendgrid = require('@sendgrid/mail');

admin.initializeApp();
admin.firestore().settings({
  timestampsInSnapshots: true
});
    exports.getMatchesNew = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      console.log("In On Call", request);
      admin.firestore().doc('city/seattle').get();

      promise.then(snapshot => {
          const data = snapshot.data();
          console.log("data: ", data);
          response.send(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle the error
        console.log(error);
        response.status(400).send(error);
      });
    });
```

and I get this error when attempting to test this function locally
using 
http://localhost:5000/wsos-base/us-central1/getMatchesNew

stack   "**ReferenceError: promise is not defined**\n    at exports.getMatchesNew.functions.https.onRequest (C:\WSOS-BASE\nitrofreddo-master\functions\index.js:317:3)\n    at cloudFunction (C:\WSOS-BASE\nitrofreddo-master\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\providers\https.js:57:9)\n    at app.use (C:\Users\miker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\src\supervisor\worker.js:151:11)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\miker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\miker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)\n    at C:\Users\miker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7\n    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\miker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)\n    at next (C:\Users\miker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)\n    at app.use (C:\Users\miker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\src\supervisor\worker.js:123:7)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\miker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)"
message "promise is not defined"
name    "ReferenceError"

I have NO information from previous developer on this. I downloaded the latest Node.JS when setting up the environment, but maybe that was incorrect. Is this a Node.Js version conflict? or a Firebase version conflict? Or ???

Please see my previous post [This shows a cloud function that is working, except for what I believe are dropped promises when trying to get user information for each mentee id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934950/broken-promise-cloud-firestore-function?noredirect=1#comment96635612_54934950)

Comment: well, I don't see `promise` being defined anywhere? Show us where its defined at.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you never defined the variable `promise`.

Instead of this:

```
admin.firestore().doc('city/seattle').get();
```

Perhaps you meant to say this:

```
const promise = admin.firestore().doc('city/seattle').get();
```

Comment: leave some for the rest of us to answer doug ;)

Comment: Doh!, Well of course the author would notice operator error. Thanks. Edited and different error.

Comment: @MikeRees If you found the solution to your problem, just answer your own question.  Please don't edit existing answers.

Comment: Noted. Thanks. Though, I did not find a solution to my problem. It led to an different error. Should I post the additional error separately? I'm really spinning my wheels here. I cannot get your samples from the referenced video to work and the error is very descriptive, code "MODULE_NOT_FOUND" (this is the result of using the url in the firebase serve command output in a browser)

Comment: If you have a new error, then it's normally best to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand it, but after rebooting my machine my function works. It's sad, but that is still a viable solution to some tech issues. 
This is the function from the referenced sample from Doug Stevenson (without my undefined 'promise' object). I feel I'm in a good place now, and will be able to chain these promises now that I have it working. Thanks to Doug, and everyone else who wants to answer but can't get there before Doug does! ;-)